# How i share post from a flutter app to another platform like twitter ,Facebook etc?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter application user can share post to various platforms like twitter,Facebook,Instagram and LinkedIn. When user share a post to any of the above platforms then that platform's webView is opened in my application. But i want that if target platform(twitter,Facebook etc) is installed in my device then it should open target platform otherwise it should open in webView in my application.

Comment: I think you should take a look into Firebase Dynamic Links

Comment: Are you using the **share** package? [https://pub.dev/packages/share](https://pub.dev/packages/share)

Comment: No, Currently I am using flutter_webview_plugin plugin.

Comment: @DhanrajVerma have u got any solution for this

Comment: @SunishaSindhu I am using [flutter_share_me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me) package but it has only android support.